# Add Redirect URL link to JS Function

Tags: php, javascript

How can I add redirect URL link to JS function (example form action to : session.php) in below code.
I've tried with another way code, but it still can't function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_butt").click(function() {
        var conf = {
            frequency: 5000,
            spread: 5,
            duration: 600
        };
        /* do your AJAX call and processing here...
        ....
        ....
        */
        // this is the call we make when the AJAX callback function indicates a login failure 
        $("#login").vibrate(conf);

        // let's also display a notification
        if($("#errormsg").text() == "")
            $("#loginform").append('<p id="errormsg">Invalid username or password!</p>');       

        // clear the fields to discourage brute forcing :)
        $("#password").val("");
        document.forms['login_form'].elements['username'].focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: php works on a server, js works on a client. You cannot add php function to js code.

Comment: Sorry, I mean how to add redirect url into JS function. I've edited my post. Sorry

Comment: `window.location.replace('http://google.com');` --- this is how you redirect in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Ref: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Did you just take another person's answer as is? http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/251311

Comment: @LearneR: well, if you use another's answer - then it makes sense to give an original reference, otherwise it looks like a theft

Comment: @zerkms: okay it wont happen again. Added the reference link.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this..

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 <script>
 function name(){
    window.location ='abc.php';
 }
 </script>
```